# Why Apache Calcite RelOptRule skips Filter Condition subquery?

Tags: java, apache-calcite

For example we have next Rel tree (with subquery in condition)

```
LogicalProject(id=[$0], varchar_col=[$1], link_col=[$2])
  LogicalFilter(condition=[IN($0, {
        LogicalSort(fetch=[1])
          LogicalProject(id=[$0])
            LogicalTableScan(table=[[db, table2]])
        })])
    LogicalTableScan(table=[[db, table1]])
```

which is created from:

```
SELECT * FROM db.table1 as b where b.id IN (select c.id from db.table2 as c limit 1)
```

If I implement RelOptRule that just looking for TableScan, it will find only one that operates with **table1**

```
new TestRule(RelOptRule.operand(LogicalTableScan.class, RelOptRule.any()), "test")
```

Is that a bug?
Common behavior is happening in RelShuttle, it will skip RelNode in condition accordingly

Answer (score 1):

It is not a bug. By design calcite rules matches only RelNodes in the call. The filter Condition would be a RexCall and the rule won't apply to it.
You might need to create a new Rule on Filter and check if the input Rex Exprs are RelNode calls ( or any other check) and then apply this rule on that and transform.
Easier would be to first break the In into a Join and then apply your rule